# How to break a equation with a single "summation symbol (\sum) " common?

Tags: equations

How to break an equation with a single summation symbol common ?
I want to write the equation like the following in two line

```
$\sum  [(a+b+c+.........+d)

    +(e+f+............+l]=0$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To break a formula into several columns, with a single “summation symbol” common, you could use (also) the enviroment `split`. See this MWE and you can also compare it with other answers. If you want increase the brackets `(` or `[`, considering that they are on two different lines, you should use (for example) `\bigl(` or `\bigr)` to not have any errors.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\sum[(a+b+c+\dotsb+d)\\
& +(e+f+\dotsb+l)]=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### ADDEDUM after the comment of the user @M. A. SARKAR

As by your request I add you other alternatives where I increased the size of the square brackets with the appropriate commands. I hope I have understood your request.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\sum\bigl[(a+b+c+\dotsb+d)\\
& +(e+f+\dotsb+l)\bigr]=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\sum\Bigl[(a+b+c+\dotsb+d)\\
& +(e+f+\dotsb+l)\Bigr]=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\sum\Biggl[(a+b+c+\dotsb+d)\\
& +(e+f+\dotsb+l)\Biggr]=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How to use the latex code  "\left[     \right]"  in the above code in order to get large 3rd bracket?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR I have edit my answer with an addendum.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR No, no, please. Can you give to the **user bgleb** the check green mark please? This is check is not mine. Just for justice.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{multlined}[0.7\linewidth]
\sum \bigl[(a+b+c+d) \\
        + (e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l)\bigr] = 0
    \end{multlined}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   

\begin{align*}
    &\sum (a+b+c+d \\ 
    &+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your answer is missed `\documentclas{...}` ...

Comment: I would replace `&\sum (a+b+c+d` by `\sum (&a+b+c+d` and probably move also the `+` before the `e` directly after the `d`.

Comment: @Zarko This example will work with any \documentclass parameter, so there is not much point including that in the example. I have included the \begin{document} in order to show that it goes in the preamble.

Comment: @Teepeemm package is included in line 1